# Правильное написание сокращений должностей

Tags: орфография, сокращения

Как правильно писать совращения "зам.()директора", "зав.()отделом"? Нужны ли точки и пробелы или это пишется одним словом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В неофициальном стиле и документах общего содержания возможно **замдиректора, завотделом (неизм.)**  
Зам. директора, зав. отделом в принципе возможно, но не в кадровых приказах, там нельзя сокращать вообще. Пробел после точки обязателен.